# Svelte iterate over array of comma separated key values

Tags: html, foreach, svelte

I am having an array of comma separated objects like... new_data = [ Max:500 , Ron:200 ]
I want to iterate over the array giving a list as Max-500 and Ron-200
In html it would look like

```
<li>Max-500</li>
<li>Ron-200</li>
```

Can I get a solution using {#each} tag in svelte? I tried

```
{#each new_data as data}
   <li>{data}</li>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` your array:

```
let new_data = ['Max:500', 'Ron:200'].map(item => item.split(':'))
```

Then use `#each` like:

```
<ul>
{#each new_data as data}
    <li>{data[0]}-{data[1]}</li>
{/each} 
</ul>
```

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/ba06eae1002345118bc3b645edb7049a?version=3.46.4

Answer (score 0):

Or like this

```
<script>
    let new_data = ['Max:500', 'Ron:200']
</script>

<ul>
{#each new_data as data}
    <li>{data.replace(':','-')}</li>
{/each} 
</ul>
```